# Whats difference between $vm.user and $vm.$data.user in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, vue-component

When you want access components data, you can access from both `$vm.user` and `$vm.$data.user`, both set and get same result,So why we have 2 ways to access data? whats difference and which one should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$data` is the actual component's data object. For convenience, Vue [proxies](https://012.vuejs.org/api/#Data_Proxying) data access to it, just like with methods, computed properties and watchers.

JavaScript engines are very good at optimizing object access, so performance-wise there would be minimal difference, and the proxy access (`$vm.user`) should be preferred.

`$data` is useful for rare situations when you want to deep-watch all of component's data, for example like this:

```
    watch: {
        $data: {
            handler() { /* ... */ },
            deep: true
        }
    },
```